# How to toggle loading data from server by click?

Tags: angular

I have click event over button that makes server request each time. I want to send request only when when `showVersions` is true. When `showVersions`

The button `historyBtn` should work as toggle.

I have tried this:

```
fromEvent(this.historyBtn.nativeElement, 'click')
                .pipe(
                    switchMap(() => {
                        return fromPromise(
                            this.mapLibrary.objectHistoryService.getHistory(),
                        );
                    }),
                )
                .subscribe((history: any) => {
                    this.loadingHistoryPlan$.next(false);
                    this.showVersions = !this.showVersions;
                    this.history = history;
                });

<button #historyBtn>Show versions</button>
<ng-container *ngIf="showVersions">
   <select>
      <option [value]="h.id" *ngFor="let h of history">
          {{ h.updatedate }}
      </option>
   </select>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the filter operator to skip click events based on some criteria: Here is an example:

```
fromEvent(this.historyBtn.nativeElement, 'click')
    .pipe(
     filter((value) => this.showVersions),
     switchMap(() => {
        return fromPromise(
          this.mapLibrary.objectHistoryService.getHistory());
      })).subscribe((history: any) => {
             this.loadingHistoryPlan$.next(false);
             this.showVersions = !this.showVersions;
             this.history = history;
  });
```

Comment: It always sends request when I click button again

Comment: Updated the answer check now.

Comment: Does not work no opening ng-container. because by default `showVersions` is false.

Comment: Change <ng-container *ngIf="showVersions"> to <ng-container *ngIf="history">, Make sure that you  have set history to null in you component/service.